# Problem using ReactiveFormsModule on newer versions of Angular

Tags: angular

I have an example that I took from a book about using ReactiveFormsModule in forms through FormControl and FormGroup.
My problem is that with Angular version 12.2.18 and node 14.17.6 it works. But it stops working when I use Angular version 16.2.4 and node 18.18.0.

when I use:

```
constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private _loginService: LoginService){
      this.form = fb.group({
          username:['',Validators.required],
          password:['',Validators.compose([Validators.required, PasswordValidator.cannotContainSpace])]
      })
}
```

the error is:

```
Error: src/app/login/login.component.ts:23:24 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(validators: null): null', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(((control: AbstractControl<any, any>) => ValidationErrors | null) | ((formControl: FormControl<any>) => { cannotContainSpace: boolean; } | null))[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'null'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(validators: (ValidatorFn | null | undefined)[]): ValidatorFn | null', gave the following error.
    Type '(formControl: FormControl<any>) => { cannotContainSpace: boolean; } | null' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn'.
      Types of parameters 'formControl' and 'control' are incompatible.
        Type 'AbstractControl<any, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'FormControl<any>': defaultValue, registerOnChange, registerOnDisabledChange

23           password:['',Validators.compose([Validators.required, PasswordValidator.cannotContainSpace])]
```

that is, it seems that the error is using Validators.compose.
when in the html file I use:

```
<div *ngIf="form.controls.password.errors.required" class="alert alert-danger">
```

the error is:

```
Error: src/app/login/login.component.html:23:43 - error TS4111: Property 'password' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['password'].

Error: src/app/login/login.component.html:23:59 - error TS4111: Property 'required' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['required'].
```

I need to create it on this last configuration. Can you explain to me what changes?

Comment: Set `noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": false,` in you `tsconfig`.

Comment: it worked. I thank you. Can you give me a little explanation?